# On a Windows 10 machine with a small eMMC main drive, Is it possible to move Dropbox to a removeable drive to save space?

Tags: windows-10, dropbox

Since it is such a small drive, it seems best to save as much as possible to another drivew

Comment: What would happen if the removable drive is not there?

Comment: I wouldn't be able to access the program and all that happens is I get a warning message to that effect.

Comment: Are you sure of that? A program that handles the error itself may reset its settings to put the download directory back where it used to be, where you don't want it.

Answer (score 0):

First, yes it is technically possible to change the location of your DropBox local folder. You will find these settings in the Dropbox client application.

Second, it is generally unwise to place data for running applications on removable media. It could just crash the application and damage the storage device, or it could change back to a local location and redownload all those files right back where you don't want them.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use settings to move it to the removable drive but Dropbox doesn't permit moving to a removable drive. An option is to selectively sync only some folders.

I figure I could copy the other folders to the removable drive even though they wouldn't update.